# How to know if new data in a RecyclerView is greater than the last updated data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating an android app and update it's data every second everything work's fine but if my data is greater than the last updated data then I have to Change my RecyclerView's Custom Adapter's TextView's Background color at Changing position.

How to know current data is greater than the last updated data.
For example, the currency price is 44.50 after some second it will be 44.52.

```
//Adapter Class
class AbcAdapter(
private val context: Context,
val list: List<DataModal>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AbcAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder 
{
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.ax_adapter, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val ax = list[position]

    holder.textSymbol.text = mcx.symbol
    holder.textBuy.text = mcx.buy
    holder.textChange.text = mcx.change

    if (holder.textChange.text.toString().toFloat() > 0) {
        holder.textChange.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"))
    } else if (holder.textChange.text.toString().toFloat() < 0) {
        holder.textChange.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))
    }

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var textSymbol: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.SymbolLabel)
    var textBuy: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.BuyPrice)
    var textChange: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ChangePrice)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyListAdapter(
  private val context: Activity,
  private val symbol: ArrayList<String>,
  private val buy: ArrayList<String>
) : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.custom_list, symbol) {

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder", "InflateParams")

override fun getView(position: Int, view: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View 
{
   val inflater = context.layoutInflater
   val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null, true)

   val symbolText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.SymbolLabel) as TextView
   val buyText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.BuyPrice) as TextView

   if(position != 0){
      //check current position data is greater than the previous data
      if(buy[position] > buy[position - 1]){
         //if it is greater than previous do the logics here...
      }
   }

  symbolText.text = symbol[position]
  buyText.text = buy[position]
  return rowView
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` gives you more granular control of each item. 
So I strongly recommend you to swtich to RecyclerView and implement [`DiffUtils`](https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00), which will call `notifydatasetchanged` internally.

Implementing RecyclerView is quite easy - if you don't want to use DiffUtils, you can directly call `notifyDataSetChanged` directly but it's quite costly. If your list is small, this might be a fast way to go.